# Django inlines do not save

Tags: python, django, admin, inline, models

I have a couple of apps that link together via `ForeignKey` and are editiable on a single page through inlines.  Problem is that though the model will save properly, the inline objects do not.

### people/models.py

Here is where my classes are created, a character with a voice actor, then that character is `ForeignKey`'d to a show.

```
from django.db import models

class VoiceActor(models.Model):   
   first_name     =     models.CharField(max_length=200)
   last_name      =     models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class Characters(models.Model):
   first_name     =     models.CharField(max_length=200)
   last_name      =     models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   voice_actor    =     models.ManyToManyField(VoiceActor, blank=True)

class ShowCharacters(models.Model):
   show           =     models.ForeignKey('info.Show')
   character      =     models.ForeignKey(Characters)
   role           =     models.ForeignKey('metadata.Roles', blank=True)
```

### info/admin.py

Where my inlines are manifested, the inline is created and is shown properly, but when edited, does not save with the Show model.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from info.models import *
from people.models import *

class CharactersInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = ShowCharacters
   extra = 0

class ShowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fieldsets = (...)
   inlines = [CharactersInline]

admin.site.register(Show, ShowAdmin)
```

I have about four different inlines similar to the above, and two inlines are handled inside the `info` app itself, and it still does not save.

**<strike>EDIT: From what I've found it could be something called `formset_save` not being called. Not really sure how to force that in though.</strike>**

Any help or criticism is appreciated, it could be that this is the wrong way to handle this. Thanks!

**EDIT 2** So after looking into it with the #Django IRC, I changed `CharactersInline` to `extra = 1`.  This resulted in displaying two fields.  I tried editing both and the first field successfully saved while the second did not.

Looking deeper into it, I noticed the template renders the first `<tr>` (the one that saves) with the `id='episodelist_set-0'` and the second with `id='episodelist_set-empty'`. For now I will be able to solve this by hiding the `set-empty` rows in my CSS.

Comment: Pretty sure you want ForeignKeys not OneToOnes in the ShowCharacter model. The way you have it, each show can only have one character, and each actor can only ever play one character as well.

Comment: That could be it, three of my inlines have a OneToOne in them. Bet that might be throwing an error and the form doesnt catch it on save. Let me try updating this to see if it works.

Comment: Looks like that didn't fix the saving issue, but that probably still helps the models in the long run.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a copy/paste issue rather than the real problem, but your first line in models: shouldn't that be from django.db import models instead of django.contrib import models?

Comment: Oh yeah it totally was, I'll fix that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd mention something I found as I have had the same problem (although it only occurred after I edited the styling for the inline template).

I used Firebug to inspect the page with the default template stying and it turns out that django hides a final empty form (your proposed temporary solution). So for me the issue was I had set `display: inline-block` on the `inline-related` class which all of the inline forms belong to (in django 1.6). To fix it I set `display: none` on the `empty-form` class, which only the final inline form belongs to.

I realise you have probably already done this as you mentioned it in the question but given the above information it might make more sense and seem like a less 'hacky' solution.
Hope this helps!